Does a booster pump and pressure tank setup require two pressure switches?
I have a booster pump (not a submerged well pump). I want to add a pressure tank to the system. The pump has a pressure switch, but it seems standard to install a pressure switch on the tank assembly as well. Can someone explain why I need two pressure switches, and should the settings be identical, or does the pump switch become redundant if there is one on the tank?

two is better than one

Depends on what the booster pump switch is sensing.
If it's output pressure, just locate the pressure tank near the output of the pump and you're done. If the two are close, a switch in the pump is near enough to be the same as a switch on the tank tee. If they are more than a couple of feet (or 600mm) apart, a single switch on the tank tee would be sufficient, but if you have one built into the pump that can't be removed, then you'll have two.
If the switch in the booster is detecting that there's sufficient input pressure so the booster pump isn't running dry, you'd have two in any case. One on the booster to allow it to run, or stop it if the supply runs out, and one on the tank to request it to run and pressurize the tank.

The switch on the tank tells the system whether or not to add water to the tank.
The switch on the pump tells the pump whether or not to run.
If you put the tank before the pump (closer to the well) and set the pressure higher than the pump, the pump won't run until the tank is below pressure.  It will exhaust the tank quickly after that.  If lower than the pump, the pump will exhaust the tank quicker from the beginning.  Higher makes more sense.
If you put the tank after the pump and only use one switch on the tank, the pump would run whenever the tank needs water.  With two switches, the pump may not always need to run to fill the tank.  Sometimes the tank may be calling for water but not need extra pressure from the pump.  The pump pressure should be at least as high as the tank pressure.
You could also use two tanks with a pump between.  Both tanks need switches.  The pump doesn't.  Whenever the tank nearer the house needs water, the pump will run.  When the tank nearer the well needs water (which can be checked with a level switch instead of a pressure switch), it will fill slowly from the well.  This helps with a well with a slow recharge, where you want to constantly draw a little water.
